# Why does the pytorch .backward() method occupies two more CPU threads when I want to restrict it to use only one CPU thread?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pytorch, cpu

I am trying to deploy my service using CPU and `pytorch`. I am asked to restrict the single-process service to use only one CPU thread. I have assigned `torch.set_num_interop_threads(1)` and `torch.set_num_threads(1)`. The question is that when I check the actual CPU thread number using `pstree <pid>` I got three. Later I found that the problem happened in `a.backward()`. If I delete this line, I got 1 threads; if I keep this line, I got 3 CPU threads. Why did it happen and what should I do to keep the CPU thread to be one?

I wrote a simple python3 script to reproduce the problem:

```py
import torch
import time
while(1):
    w = torch.Tensor([2])
    w = torch.autograd.Variable(w, requires_grad=True)
    x = torch.rand([1])
    x = torch.autograd.Variable(x, requires_grad=True)
    y = x**w
    y.backward()
    time.sleep(3)
```

Run it and use `pstree <pid>` to check the CPU threads, I got `python───2*[{python}]`, but if I delete `y.backward()` I got only `python`. I believe the extra two CPU threads in this script is in the same problem with my service code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As far as I can tell, `pytorch` has several methods called `backward`. Try to simplify a copy of your service to a minimal example that _only_ runs `a.backward()` but still shows the problem, and edit your question to show that code.

Comment: @dcorking Thank you for replying! I wrote a simple python3 script to reproduce the problem (the code is added in the question.)
Run it and use 'pstree <pid>' to check the CPU threads, I got 'python───2*[{python}]', but if I delete 'y.backward()' I got only 'python'. I believe the extra two CPU threads in this script is in the same problem with my service code.
Thank you!